# Laravel session not working when switching protocol (https to http or http to https)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am currently developing an App where i have to secure few pages using `SSL`. For example, Login, register pages. However, when protocol switches between `https` to `http`, Laravel session is not transmitted over HTTP.

is there any solution, Laravel will keep the session for both protocol.

Comment: In app/config/session.php 'secure' => false ` ? You had edit it?

Comment: My configuration file does not has anything like that.However, I will try that.

Comment: @pleasedeleteme not working.

Comment: Can you describe your session.php in your question?

Comment: what do you wanna know? `'driver' => 'native'` and `'secure' => false`

Comment: @Anam - Can we assume that you cleared the browser cache and created a new session? Keep in mind that this option will make it impossible to keep a safe session.

Comment: @martinstoeckli, I just tried still not working.

Comment: Can you add another one in your session.php 'http_only' => false,

Comment: What 'http_only' does?

Comment: @Anam see at https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1462 issue.

Answer (score 4):

By default, Laravel is setting secure and/or httponly for auth and session cookies. I could not find a way to change this in configuration, and infact **in Laravel 4.0** (this is no longer the case), the httponly is hard coded as a setting in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/SessionManager.php`

Note that you should not leak cookies from HTTPS to HTTP, because it stops you from being able to keep sessions secure (I could still sniff a session from another user on my network logged into your website, for example).

## Laravel 4.1+

Edit `app/config/session.php`. Change the `'secure'` key to false if you want cookies set on https to also be read on http.

Alternatively, follow @martinstoeckli's advice and set the key depending on the value of your environment.

## Laravel 4.0

Maybe the best way to implement this would be to replace `CookieSessionHandler` with your own handler.

For example, a new class could be created which would extend CookieSessionHandler with an updated write function which would mark all cookies as not being for https/http only.

```
Class NewCookieSessionHandler extends CookieSessionHandler implements \SessionHandlerInterface {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function write($sessionId, $data)
    {
        // $this->cookie is \Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar
        $this->setCookie($this->cookie->make($sessionId, $data, $this->minutes, '/', false, false));
    }

    /**
     * Set the given cookie in the headers.
     *
     * @param  \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie  $cookie
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setCookie($cookie)
    {
        if (headers_sent()) return;

        setcookie($cookie->getName(), $cookie->getValue(), $cookie->getExpiresTime(), $cookie->getPath(), $cookie->getDomain(), false, false);
    }
    
}
```

Then inside `app/config/session.php` you can change the driver to `NewCookie`

and finally inside `app/start/global.php` register your new cookie driver that overrides setting the cookie

```
use Illuminate\Cache\Repository;

Cookie::extend('NewCookie', function($app)
{
    return new NewCookieSessionHandler;
});
```

Comment: where do you put this class `NewCookieSessionHandler`?

Comment: Anywhere you can load a library/class from should be ok, there is no huge need to go overbaord. Just note that this is for older laravel's.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem not only with Laravel. You have to decide whether the cookie containing the session-id is restricted to HTTPS only, or if you send it to HTTP pages too.

- If the cookie is restricted to HTTPS pages, it will not be sent by
  the browser to unsafe HTTP requests. In this case you will loose the
  session  when switching to HTTP pages.
- If the cookie is sent to HTTPS and HTTP pages, an attacker can read the session-id and therefore impersonate the user, when he can listen to an HTTP request. The cookie will be sent not only with html requests, but also with every request for pictures and other resources.

The config can be found in the `\app\config\session.php` file and is called `secure`. If you want to set it to true only on the live site (but not for development), you could write something like that:

```
'secure' => App::environment('production'),
```

To handle this problem you would have to split the two concerns, maintaining the session and authentication. I wrote a small [article](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#ssl_nomim_cookie) about this topic with example code. Keep in mind that when you switch between the protocols, you are always prone to an SSL-strip attack, so you may think about using **HTTPS for the whole site**. For todays servers this should not be a problem anymore.